# Running liquibase in java code

Tags: java, command-line, liquibase

I'm trying to execute in Java code analogue of Ant's "updateDatabase" task:

```
Main.main( new String[]{"--defaultsFile=db/properties/db.test.properties --logLevel=debug update"} );
```

First, I could not find an updateDatabase command. I've tried: `update, updateSQL,` but all the time I'm getting:

```
Errors:
  Command not passed
```

My db.test.properties file if it may help:

```
#liquibase.properties
driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
url: jdbc:hsqldb:mem:datasourcedb
username: TEST
password: TEST
changeLogFile: db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

I've used the ":" symbol as a separator in property file as described in [liquibase.properties](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/liquibase.properties)

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use separate strings instead of one big String:

```
Main.main( new String[]{
   "--defaultsFile=db/properties/db.test.properties",
   "--logLevel=debug",
   "update"
} );
```